# How do I make option labels conditional in Ionic Framework's action sheets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want the options in my Ionic action sheet to change text based on a condition. Specifically, I want the option to read "Flag" if a list item is not flagged ($scope.flag = false), and "Unflag" if it's flagged ($scope.flag = true).

Right now, I have the text label reading:

```
<div ng-show="flag">Flag</div> <div ng-show="!flag">Unflag</div>
```

But it's not working. Instead, all I see are both options. Does anyone know how to fix this? My full code is below and in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ssktanaka/pen/bVrOpq).

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-list>
       <ion-item on-hold="showActionSheet()">
       Item 1
       </ion-item>      
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicActionSheet, $ionicListDelegate) {
    $scope.flag = true;
    $scope.showActionSheet = function() {
    // Show the action sheet
    var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [
        { text: '<div ng-show="flag">Flag</div><div ng-show="!flag">Unflag</div>' },
        ],
        titleText: 'Action Sheet',
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        cancel: function() {
         // add cancel code..
        },
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
            $scope.flag = !$scope.flag ;  
            return true;
        }
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For current versions(2+) of Ionic you can use `*ngIf` to accomplish this. To solve the flag/unflag problem you can do something like:

```
<ion-label *ngIf="flag">Flag</ion-label>
<ion-label *ngIf="!flag">Unflag</ion-label>
```

You can replace the ion-label with button, etc.